# Boolean method with an incorrect input

Tags: java, boolean

I'm a bit stuck on an exercice I have to make and I can't figure out the best way to do it.

I have to make a method that asks a question and expects Y or N. So I thought I would make a boolean method to return true or false, but the problem is that it would also return false if the user puts something other than Y or N. If I'm not mistaken, a boolean method cannot return null.

I'm very new to java and I'm not very far in my course so this problem will probably have a very simple solution. I also tried looking for an answer but didn't seem to find what I was looking for.

This is what I have with the boolean method but i'm not quite happy with it:

```
    public static boolean test() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("question");
        String reponse = sc.next();

            if (reponse.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (reponse.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                return false;
        }
            else {
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, what do you want your method to do if the input is neither "y" nor "n"? Ask for another input? Throw an error and stop the program? If you want to `return null` for that case you could simply use the Object type `Boolean` instead of the primitive `boolean`

Comment: I'd like it to print an error message and ask it again. In that case I can make a loop but the method still requires a return after that which cannot be true or false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your comment you want your program to ask for input again if the input is neither "y" nor "n". You can achieve that behavior by adding an extra loop:

```
public static boolean test() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("question");
    String response = sc.next();

    while(!response.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && !response.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
        // loop as long as input is neither "y" nor "n" (ignoring case)
        System.out.println("Please enter 'y' or 'n'");
        reponse = sc.next();
    }
    // if the loop is done input has to be either "y" or "n" at this point
    return reponse.equalsIgnoreCase("y");
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. As I thought, the answer is very simple. Something I miss to see the simplest answers :( Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need only one condition `equalsIgnoreCase("Y")`, result of its evaluation is basically the return value. All the `if`-statements in your code are redundant.

```
public static boolean test() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("question");
    String reponse = sc.next();
    
    return reponse.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
}
```

Comment: That is indeed much better but any other input would still return false. It can only be false if N was given as input

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at the end you are explicitly telling java to return false when neither a Y or N is entered. I would try putting in another else statement to have the user re-enter the data or just notify them that they have entered the wrong value.

```
public static boolean test() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("question");
    String reponse = sc.next();

    while(!response.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") ||!response.equalsIgnoreCase("N"){
          #Do something here until 
          the user inputs the correct value.
    }
        
}
```